# Why is my program writing <function convert at 0x02DE8C00> to my file?

Tags: python

```
def convert(score): 
    if score >= '90':
        msg = "Congratulations! You earned an A!"
        (msg)

    elif score >= '80':
        msg = "You earned a B; good job!"
        (msg)

    elif score >= '70':
        msg = "You earned a C; looks like you need to study a little harder."
        (msg)

    elif score >= '60':
        msg = "You earned a D; maybe you should consider tutoring"
        (msg)

    else:
        score < '60'
        msg = "I'm sorry; you failed."
        (msg)


    return convert

def main():
    infilename = input("Please enter the name of the input file: ") 
    outfilename = input("Please enter the name of the output file: ")

    infile = open(infilename,"r")
    outfile = open(outfilename,"w")

    for line in infile: 
        msg = convert(line) 
        print(msg,file=outfile)

    infile.close()
    outfile.close()

main()
```

The grades are supposed to print to a file, but when I open the file, all it says is: `<function convert at 0x02DE8C00>`. If I run the code, and don't try to print it to a file, it works fine.

OK, they want me to add more details, but I can't really think of anything else to add, I think you get it.

What have I done wrong this time?

Answer (score 7):

Your function returns itself (`return convert`) instead of `msg`.